# Asymptotic expansion of $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ as $x\to\infty$. ("Calculus" (in Japanese) by Kohji Kasahara)

Tags: calculus, analysis, asymptotics

I am reading "Calculus" (in Japanese) by Kohji Kasahara.

The following example is from this book.

> Example 2.
> Asymptotic expansion of $f(x)=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ as $x\to\infty$.
> $$\log f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\log(1+x)=\frac{1}{x}\log x + \frac{1}{x}\log(1+\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\\=\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$
> So, $f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}.$
> So, $$f(x)\\=1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)^2+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\\
> =1+\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{2x^2}\left(\log x\right)^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \,\,\,\,(x\to\infty).$$

I cannot derive $f(x)=1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)^2+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$

My attempt is here:

$$f(x)=1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)^2+o\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)^2\right).$$

And
$$o\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\log x+\frac{1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)^2\right)=o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}(\log x)^2+\frac{1}{x^4}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2+\frac{2}{x^3}\log x + \frac{2}{x^2}o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\frac{2}{x}\log x \cdot o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\\=o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}(\log x)^2+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right).$$

Comment: I would use $e^w=1+w+\frac{w^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(w^3)$. With the weaker error term $o(w^2)$, you cannot prove $o(1/x^2)$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you very much for your answer!